# Getting checkboxes values on email with method="post"

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a contact form with drop downs, checkboxes and radio options but i can't make the checkboxes to be send to my email
I tried this:

```
<label class="labelleft">¿Cómo se enteró de nosotros?</label>
        <label class="labelright"><input type="checkbox" name="findout[]" value="Email" />Email</label>
        <label class="labelright"><input type="checkbox" name="findout[]" value="Buscador"/>Buscador</label>
        <label class="labelright"><input type="checkbox" name="findout[]" value="Revista"/>Revista</label>
        <label class="labelright"><input type="checkbox" name="findout[]" value="Expo"/>Expo</label>
        <label class="labelright"><input type="checkbox" name="findout[]" value="Redes Sociales"/>Redes Sociales</label>
```

Im using this:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="enviar.php">
```

and the php is:

```
<?php 
$mail='mail@mail.com'; 

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email= $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$giro = $_POST['giro'];
$negocio = $_POST['negocio'];
$dist = $_POST['dist'];
$findout = $_POST['findout'];
$rb= $_POST ['rbtn'];
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$thank="gracias.html"; 
$message = " 
Nombre: " .$name." 
Correo Electronico: " .$email." 
Telefono: " .$phone." 
Compania: " .$giro." $rb
Tipo de Negocio: ".$negocio."
Distribuidor: ".$dist."
Se entero: ".$findout."
Mensaje: " .$message."
"; 

if (mail($mail,"NIBO",$message)) 
Header ("Location: $thank"); 

?>
```

I just posted the html part of the checkboxes.
When i send the email all im getting is the word "Array"

Not 100% sure what im doing wrong.
Thanks in advance for any help or tips!

Comment: You could use a `foreach` for your checkboxes. I.e.: `foreach($_POST['findout'] as $check){echo $check;}`

Comment: `$findout` is an array of checked values.  You need to use something like `implode(',', $findout)` to get a string you can use in your email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `foo[]` naming hack in PHP causes `foo` to be an array in $_POST. Since you're just directly copying that array to a variable:

```
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
```

and then embedding that var in your email, you'll just get

```
Se entero: Array
```

in your email. You'll have to do something like:

```
$foo = implode(',', $_POST['foo']);
```

to convert the array into a plain string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$findout = $_POST['findout'];
```

Is an array of singular values you need to loop through them to get each value

```
$findout = "";
foreach($_POST['findout'] as $findout){
   $findout .= "{$findout} ";
}
$findout = rtrim($findout);
```

Then format your string depending on how you want it to look

Comment: Mark B has used a different method to me, his is better for this situation.